# Is this normal CPU temperature?

Tags: cpu, temperature, desktop-computer

My power supply fan has suddenly started becoming really noisy and I am wondering if it is affecting my CPU temperature.

I have a desktop with a 6-core CPU. This is what CPU Thermometer shows me:

[image]

Is this normal temperature for this load?

Comment: That's not bad. My laptop idles at 80C.

Comment: -@DanD. you should get that checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your ambient temperature, this seems very good to me for an idling processor.

Expect about Ambient + 10C at idle on average

Comment: well the weather report in my area says its 16C, so i guess that tells what the ambient temperature is...

Comment: The ambient temperature is the temperature in the environment around the equipment.  37C is body temperature, so if your house is 10 degrees lower than that, then you are probably chilly, but your equipment is fine.  That seems to be a reasonable temperature for a home or office setting.  If it is outside, then you have a heating issue, as those temps are high for that low load.  Consider cleaning the fans and ensuring your heatsinks are connected properly.

Comment: Chilly at 27C? More like balmy. That would be 81F. :-)

Comment: Yeah, my conversions aren't great.

Comment: Heh, I would be way too hot at 27C. Germany is under zero degrees celsius right now, 21C is good for us ;D

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact you have a desktop, this isn't just down to the CPU. Given you might have high powered RAM and GPU these also contribute to the noise your computer makes. Open her up and have a look. Nothing like a bit of good observation to find out what's making the noise.

Depending on your hardware, this may be a better system monitor for your machine:

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html